# Configure SpringSecurity to use JWT

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I have a personal web project (Struts-Hibernate) protected by SpringSecurity 3.2.2, and I have been reading about JWT so I want to improve my project to use it, I have been reading some tutorials but I can´t figure out how to do it.

Right now, I use springSecurity xml file to load the configuration where a class named CustomProviderAuthentication it's in charge of throw an Exception or return a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(from Spring) according to the case.

this is my springSecurity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.authentication.*" />

<http auto-config="true">
   <intercept-url pattern="/security/**" access="ROLE_Usuario" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/security/**" access="ROLE_Usuario" />
    <form-login always-use-default-target="true" 
        login-page="/loginAction" default-target-url="/security/adminPanel"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginAction?auth=failure" />
</http>

<!-- <beans:bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.test.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/> -->

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.test.authentication.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

My doubts are:

- 1) Once the user is logged in, Where should I return the generated token?
- 2) How can I configure spring security filter to use token instead of a Session?
- 3) How can I configure Spring security filter to redirect to login if token it's not present?

Hints are appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this will vary considerably between Spring Security versions; you'll need to specify which you're using.

Comment: @chrylis, I forgot it, but it's SpringSecurity 3.2.2

Comment: Ouch. I'm not sure that the JWT libraries support that far back.

Comment: @chrylis, I can try to use a newer version, can you give me some guidance about how to set up de security filter to turn this stateless and use JWT?

Comment: @chrylis, is the right path add a filter before on my springsecurity xml, and if I found a JWT on the header of the request I should skip the springsecurity filter, if that it´s possible?